# How to post a very long URL using Python - Requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

The URL is something like below and very lengthy and might stretch to more than 1 page.

http://example.com:8080/testAPI/testAPIServlet?id=123|345................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................|789&rows=200

This type of url is not supported using requests.get method. So I want to use requests.post method to get the response. Please help.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a GET and POST request? `requests` doesn't impose a length limit on the query string, but the *server* might.

Comment: Thanks Martijin.. but when I used requests.get() for this lengthy url I got a status code as 400 and also the response was null. One of my colleague then suggested me to use POST method. So need help in this regard. Also please let me know how do I get to know the query limit on the server side?

Comment: You cannot query a server to ask them for their limits, no. A 400 error response *could* be indicating that the query string is too long, it could also be that the server found something else wrong. If shorter variants of the same parameters work, then length is the most likely cause of the error code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martijn for that quick response and solution :)

Comment: That's what the problem is in our case... the query string is too long and I wanted a solution for that, there is no way I can make it shorter. It has to be that way. I am not sure how to tackle this. The get and post both worked well for shorter length queries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`requests` doesn't really impose a length limit on the query string, but your server *might*. Certain browsers also limit URL lengths to about 2000 characters.

Making a POST request with the same data with `requests` is trivial; pass a dictionary of the fields to the `data` keyword argument and use the `requests.post()` function:

```
url = 'http://example.com:8080/testAPI/testAPIServlet'
params = {'id': '123|345.....................................|789',
          'rows': 200}
response = requests.post(url, data=params)
```

This echoes the `GET` request variant, where you'd have used the `params` keyword argument instead.